# Turn "about:config" into a hyperlink

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

When answering a question, is there any way to turn the string "about:config" into a hyperlink that will open exactly that ("about:config", a [feature](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config) of Mozilla applications) when clicked on?

It seems that "http://" is required at the beginning of a hyperlink for it to be recognized as such. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like that link will work anyway, probably a security feature of Firefox:

http://jsbin.com/ogobo

```
<a href="about:config">about:config</a>
```

If that worked, you could have cheated and used a service like tinyurl to get around the markdown "bug":

[about:blank](http://tinyurl.com/18r)

Comment: I can't get markdown to link to `about:blank` though...

Comment: You're right, it appears as a hyperlink at jsbin but nothing happens when I click on it. I thought it would work because http://kb.mozillazine.org/About%3aconfig have a bunch of them which I can click and the correct page would open...but I just now realized they're being turned into links automatically by the Linkification Firefox addon I have installed (and completely forgot about).

Comment: Interestingly, such a link seems to work when you right click and open in a new window/tab.